# RxSwift: single observable self is nil

Tags: ios, rx-swift, xcode11, swift5

I'm trying to implement `RxSwift` single observable:

```
class Doctor {
    var disposeBag = DisposeBag()

    func sanityCheck() -> Single<String> {
        return Single<String>.create {[weak self] observer in
            if self?.amICrazy() == true {
                observer(.success("Yes, you are crazy"))
            }else {
                observer(.error(someError.notCrazy))
            }
            return Disposables.create()
        }
    }

    func amICrazy() -> Bool {
        return arc4random_uniform(2) == 0
    }
}
```

But the problem the `self` is always nil.

Any of you knows why `self` is nil or how can fix it?

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: Please add code, where you calling `Doctor.sanityCheck()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You using `weak` capture for `self` in creation closure for `Single`, so unless you hold strong reference on your `Doctor` object, it will be deallocated as soon as you leave allocation context.

BTW, in latest swift you can use `Bool.random()` to get random boolean value.

```swift
func amICrazy() -> Bool {
    return Bool.random() // or just .random()
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
func sanityCheck() -> Single<String> {
    func amICrazy() -> Bool {
        return Bool.random()
    }
    return Single<String>.create { observer in
        if amICrazy() {
            observer(.success("Yes, you are crazy"))
        }else {
            observer(.error(SomeError.notCrazy))
        }
        return Disposables.create()
    }
}

enum SomeError: Error {
    case notCrazy
}
```

If you don't have a `self` you don't have to worry about self being nil.